# Ansible automatic ssh authentication using passphrase protected private key

Tags: windows-11, openssh, ansible, debian-bullseye

I can't seem to get ansible to automatically pick up the SSH identity that I've added, and if I am prompted for the passphrase on my private key my passphrase seems to not be accepted, while the same passphrase is accepted when just SSH'ing without ansible. If I change the playbook to use the directives `become: yes`, `become_user: <Windows user>` and `ansible_shell_type: cmd` the script runs, but I still have to enter the passphrase multiple times...

- Source host is Raspberry Pi running Debian Bullseye
- Destination host is Thinkpad T580 running Windows 11

### ✅ SSH without ansible

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh-agent bash
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa (pi)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh my_user@192.168.178.170
...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1265]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

my_user@MY_LAPTOP C:\Users\my_user>
// Works fine without any password or passphrase ✅
```

### /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

### /etc/ansible/hosts

```
[local]
my_laptop ansible_host=192.168.178.170 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=my_user
```

### ~/ansible/playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Fetch public key
  hosts: my_laptop
  gather_facts: yes
  vars: 
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa # <- With or without?
    
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch temporary key
      fetch:
        src: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        dest: /tmp/id_rsa.pub
        flat: yes
```

### ❌ With `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`:

I enter the passphrase 3 times, then it continues on to say there is no permission to create the `/tmp/` directory

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
fatal: [my_laptop]: UNREACHABLE! => {
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. 
Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. 
Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1676947350.1170616-19638-181124692161141 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1676947350.1170616-19638-181124692161141=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1676947350.1170616-19638-181124692161141 `\" ), exited with result 1",
  "unreachable": true
}
```

### ❌ Without `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`:

```
fatal: [my_laptop]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: my_user@192.168.178.170: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

##### Windows Event Viewer Logs:

`sshd: Connection closed by authenticating user my_user 192.168.178.20 port 42742 [preauth]`

## ❓ Questions

1. Why does it ask for a password when creating an ssh connection without ansible directly logging me in?
2. Why does it say I have no permission?

   - **Answer**: This was due to not using the `become` directive in combination with the correct `become_user` (Windows username).
3. When it is talking about having no permission, is it referring to the source host `pi@raspberrypi`, or the destination host `my_user@my_laptop`?

   - **Answer**: The destination host `my_user@my_laptop`.
4. Do I need to create the var `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` in my playbook? Or should ansible automatically find the identity in the `ssh-agent`?

Thanks in advance.

## ❗ **Update**

I managed to some fix *some* issues;

- OpenSSH wasn't set up properly on my Windows machine. I found [these Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx7WPDnwcDg) very helpful
- My playbook was incorrect. **Make sure the following directives are filled in when using a Windows-managed host with ansible**:

  - `become: yes`
  - `become_user: <Your Windows user>`
  - `ansible_shell_type: cmd` *(Set to `cmd` or `powershell`, but when using `powershell` [extra config is needed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_setup.html#configuring-ansible-for-ssh-on-windows))*.

### `~/playbook.yml` so far:

```
---
- name: Fetch public key
  hosts: my_laptop
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  become_user: my_user
  vars_files:
    - secrets.yml
  vars: 
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
    ansible_shell_type: cmd

  tasks:
    - name: Fetch temporary key
      fetch:
        src: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        dest: /tmp/id_rsa.pub
        flat: yes
...
```

The script runs now but prompts me for the passphrase 3 times.

```
PLAY [Fetch public key] *************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ok: [my_laptop]

TASK [Fetch temporary key] **********************************************************************************************************************************
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ok: [my_laptop]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
my_laptop                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

### ❓ New questions:

5. Why is it still asking the passphrase for the private key, and not taking it from ssh-agent?
6. Why should i enter the passphrase 3 times, once while gathering facts and another two times while executing the task?

Comment: 5. maybe because when ansible is logging in you don't have an agent ? run debug for task: `shell: ssh-agent -s .. register: output` then `debug, var=output` you'll see ...

Comment: Are you adding the right key? In the manual ssh example you use `/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa` but in ansible you use `/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa`. Which one did you ssh-add to the agent to unlock?

Comment: You would normally set the private key type and shell in the inventory rather than the playbook, btw.